# How to add Viewpager in Android Listview rows?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-viewpager

I have a `Layout` file having `ImageView` and `TextView` which is perfectly works fine. Now, after adding some requirement I have multiple Images for each row of `ListView`. So, that user can slide the `ImageView` in each row and can see multiple Images of current row.

I thought to implement it with `viewpager` but not able to figure it out How to do it?

Please let me know any tutorial or Hinted solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the problem you encountered? ViewPager is just a view like many others. If it helps, try switching to a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Actually I don't want to put horizonrtalScrollView because I am also transforming the image throguh picasso and adding left right button to open next view pager in each row

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution below. First class is a PagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Images> pagerItems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public ViewPageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Images> pagerItems) {
    super();
    this.pagerItems = pagerItems;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, container, false);

    container.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
    return view.equals(obj);
}
}
```

Use this below code in you listview's getView method

```
ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(context, images);
view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ListView adapter is also loading the data for `TextView`. Is it going to affect it?

Comment: send you data as a object to adapter and set the values there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and let me try it first :)

Comment: I am little bit confused here what is `view_layout` in your above code because I only have one layout file which have `TextView` and just after it has `ViewPager` . I am rendering `TextView` from `ListViewAdapter` class. So is this for rendering the samelayout but only for `ViewPager` right?

If yes, Do I need to send it through `ListViewAdapter` or it is already passing thorugh context?

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Do you want me to paste my code here